# Hibernate MapKeyManyToMany gives composite key where none exists

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jboss, dictionary, composite-key

I have a Hibernate (3.3.1) mapping of a map using a three-way join table:

```
@Entity
public class SiteConfiguration extends ConfigurationSet {
  @ManyToMany
  @MapKeyManyToMany(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="SiteTypeInstallationId"))
  @JoinTable(
    name="SiteConfig_InstConfig",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="SiteConfigId"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="InstallationConfigId")
  )
  Map<SiteTypeInstallation, InstallationConfiguration>
    installationConfigurations = new HashMap<SiteTypeInstallation, InstallationConfiguration>();
...
}
```

The underlying table (in Oracle 11g) is:

```
Name                           Null     Type      
------------------------------ -------- ----------
SITECONFIGID                   NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
SITETYPEINSTALLATIONID         NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
INSTALLATIONCONFIGID           NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
```

The key entity used to have a three-column primary key in the database, but is now redefined as:

```
@Entity
public class SiteTypeInstallation implements IdResolvable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator="SiteTypeInstallationSeq", strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "SiteTypeInstallationSeq", sequenceName = "SEQ_SiteTypeInstallation", allocationSize = 1)
  long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="SiteTypeId")
  SiteType siteType;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="InstalationRoleId")
  InstallationRole role;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="InstallationTypeId")
  InstType type;

...
}
```

The table for this has a primary key 'Id' and foreign key constraints+indexes for each of the other columns:

```
Name                           Null     Type      
------------------------------ -------- ----------
SITETYPEID                     NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
INSTALLATIONROLEID             NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
INSTALLATIONTYPEID             NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
```

For some reason, Hibernate thinks the key of the map is composite, even though it isn't, and gives me this error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK1A241BE195C69C8:SiteConfig_InstConfig  [SiteTypeInstallationId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (SiteTypeInstallation [SiteTypeId,InstallationRoleId])

If I remove the annotations on `installationConfigurations` and make it transient, the error disappears.

I am very confused why it thinks SiteTypeInstallation has a composite key at all when @Id is clearly defining a simple key, and doubly confused why it picks exactly just those two columns. Any idea why this happens? Is it possible that JBoss (5.0 EAP) + Hibernate somehow remembers a mistaken idea of the primary key across server restarts and code redeployments?

Thanks in advance,
-Lars